# Обновление версии Android

Tags: android

Допустим у приложения, установленного на телефон, максимальная версия Android 5.1. На телефон приходит обновление Android 6.0. Как будет себя вести приложение после этого?

Comment: Нормально. Как хорошее послушное приложение :)

Comment: @АндрейКасьянов Разве крашей не будет? А если пользователь решит разрешения какие убрать?

Comment: На сколько я понимаю редактировать конкретные разрешения можно если у приложения стоит targetsdk=23 если приложение собрано на более ранних версиях SDK то все должно быть по старому. Вполне могу ошибаться

Comment: проблем быть не должно, а каким образом пользователь может убрать  разрешения не редактируя код?

Comment: @Александр В настройках приложения, на сколько я помню.

Comment: @Александр в android 6.0 это возможно.

Comment: @iamtihonov, а о каких разрешениях идет речь?)

Comment: Да в 6 версии можно как при установке так и в настройках разрешить или запретить определенные разрешения которые запрашивает приложение. Я думаю google позаботился о совместимости :))

http://www.howtogeek.com/230683/how-to-manage-app-permissions-on-android-6.0/

Вот вообщем нашел. Для старых версий будет выводиться предупреждение о том что приложение может работать не корректно. Но возможность запретить все же есть

Comment: тогда интересно, но все же, проблем быть не должно

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если `targetSdkVersion` 23 и выше то permissions будут устанавливаться в рантайме и их можно отключить, за исключение разве что `android.permission.INTERNET`.

Если `targetSdkVersion` 22 и ниже то все permissions будут предоставлены при установке, но их можно отключить - при этом будет всплывать диалог что это не рекомендуется, т.к. это нарушит работу приложения.

Если юзер таки отключит permissions то он ССЗБ и поведение приложения неопределенно. Но Google постаралась учесть и этот случай: большинство отключенных permissions не будут вызывать краши, а просто предоставлять пустышки. Например если юзер отключил `permission` `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` то просто будет возвращаться ноль контактов.